# Put terminal command into graphical icon

Tags: command-line, scripts

I installed SCID, a GUI (chess) application, via downloading the sourcecode from "http://sourceforge.net/projects/scidvspc/"
I then unpacked that and navigated my terminal to the respective directory. I entered "./configure" and then " sudo make install"
I can open that programm entering scid in the terminal. Now I want something, i can click and drag into the bar on the left, that does exactly that.

Kind regards

Markus

Comment: You need a script and a `yourscript.desktop` file

Comment: To get it clear, you need a launcher to start 2 applications instead of only one?

Comment: If you type in the terminal `scid`, it should work as well for `Exec=scid` Are we talking about this one:  http://scid.sourceforge.net/download.html

Comment: My (implicit) suggestion was to put into `Exec=` the path to the executable script you already have; for example, if the script is in your home directory: `Exec=/home/username/script.sh`, where "username" is your username. That way you could put both commands  into the script. If those are two applications that need to be run simultaneously then let us know, because further adjustments will be needed.

Comment: To save you the time of creating a launcher, scid is in the software center *and* has a launcher of its own already in Dash. Please clarify a bit what is exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: @MarkusGratis way long winded. You don't need to create a script for this. Just use `Exec=scid` in the desktop file, like Jacob suggested.

Comment: @MarkusGratis nono, an executable can be called directly by a `.desktop` file, no script in between needed. Scid, as mentioned, already has a launcher when installed from Software Center, and it is not a terminal application, as your launcher suggests.

Comment: @Jacob Vlijm to be specific I am using scid vs pc. 4.13, installed that from source code as it was not in my Software Center Repositories.

I took your suggestion as creating a .desktop file via:

"sudo -i gedit /usr/share/applications/scid.desktop"

and putting "Then [Desktop Entry]

Type=Application

Terminal=true

Name=SCID

Icon=/home/lakis01/Schach/scid_vs_pc-4.13/icons/scid.png

Exec= scid"

in there, but I get the error "could not launch application" there.

Comment: no it is "http://scidvspc.sourceforge.net/"

Comment: @MarkusGratis (not sure if I should summarize some things in an answer), but a few things: 1. `scid`, as it seems, is no terminal application, you should leave out the line `Terminal=true` 2. If an application is installed locally, keep its launcher in `~/.local/share/applications`, if it is installed globally, in `/usr/share/applications`. Your icon ('s path) suggests a local install, however the command `scid` makes clear the application is in `$PATH`?

Comment: To the close voters: scid is not a script, OP tries to find out some basic stuff about running an application without an existing launcher *at all*. The suggested dupe causes the mistake `Terminal=true`...

Comment: I'm curious, is the second time you have said it, so: did you actually put `Then` as the first word of your .desktop file?

Comment: yes, I did put Then in the beginning. I tried leaving out the Terminal=True, but that didn't help either.
I am sorry my lack of understanding does not particularly help, but I thought there was a trivial solution. I would not mind a terminal popping up and the computer typing scid and entering as long as i can drag that executable into the bar on the left.

Comment: @MarkusGratis I am afraid your question is not answerable as it is, it is currently unclear how you exactly installed it, and the information you give us is contradictionary in more than one way. (Although the close reason is *duplicate*, my vote is *unclear what you are asking*. Please edit the question and add how and where you exactly installed it, if you edited `$PATH` etc etc.

Comment: Ok, so i now remove the old version 4.13 and got the new one from "http://sourceforge.net/projects/scidvspc/files/source/scid_vs_pc-4.14.tgz/download"

i unpacked that and navigated my terminal to the respective directory.

I entered "./configure" and then

" sudo make install"

I can open that programm entering scid in the terminal.

Now I want something i can click that does exactly that.

Comment: @MarkusGratis please edit all relevant information, as clear, complete and detailed as possible into the question, and it'll get automatically into review for re- opening.

Answer (score 0):

*First create an icon for launcher by copying the png to shared location:*

```
cd ~/Downloads/Scid vs PC/scid_vs_pc-4.16.1/icons
sudo cp scid.png /usr/share/pixmaps
```

*Next, create desktop launcher file:*

```
cd /usr/share/applications 
sudo nano Scid-vs-PC.desktop
```

*Contents for Launcher file:*

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Scid vs. PC
Comment=Scid vs. PC ver 4.16.1 (07/2016)
Type=Application
Exec=/usr/local/bin/scid
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/scid.png
Terminal=false
Categories=Game
```

*...and now I can see Scid vs. PC  in the dash search - works for 16.04*